# UPS Shipping module not working on Linux environment

Tags: php, linux, prestashop-1.6, ups

I am using Free UPS Carrier Module in my project built on PrestaShop and this module is working fine on my Localhost(WINDOWS-XAMPP) but when going on server(Red Hat LINUX) the **Prestashop could not connect to UPS webservices.**

Seems something wrong with server connection.

I also checked my server error log files and could not find anything to share here.
Please guide me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: I also checked my server error log files and could not find anything to share here

Answer (score 0):

Actually there were no error with the code but I just just used CURL instead of using stream_context_create and now it worked !